# Why am I getting "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type" when trying to use a @Repository JPARepository using java -cp?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

First I have looked through the other answers and tried everything I could find nothing seems to work.

I have the following simple JPARepository

```
@Repository
public interface ResultsRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {}
```

I have a service like...

```
@Service
public class Service {
    @Autowired
    ResultsRepository repo;
    ....
}
```

this is called from a `CommandLineRunner`...

```
@Component
public class OTMRunner implements CommandLineRunner {
    private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(OTMRunner.class);

    @Autowired
    private Service service;

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
       ...
    }
}
```

And an Application where I am setting the scan package manually just to be sure...

```
// Also tried without scan base package.
@SpringBootApplication(
        scanBasePackages = {"my.package.*"}
)
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(Application.class)
                .web(WebApplicationType.NONE)
                .run(args);
    }
}
```

I have the following in my pom...

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Everything seems to run fine when I use a JUnit IT but I need to run it from the cmd line to add ars and properties to the classpath....

```
java -cp "JAR_LOCATION;PROPERTIES_LOCATION" my.package.Application PARAM
```

A couple of important points...

***I Cannot use mvn spring-boot:run or java -jar***

This does not work because I can't dynamically add to the classpath. Also I don't seem to be able to pass in Param.

**I also already tried**

```
@EnableJpaRepositories("my.package.repository")
@EntityScan(
        basePackages = {"my.package"}
)
```

On the application but that did not help either. Can anyone see what I am missing?

**UPDATE**

I can confirm the only change needed to get it to "work" is to comment out the @Repository which means it is something related to the way Spring is wiring the interfaces.

Comment: You're not supposed to put `@Repository` on interfaces (not even Spring Data ones)

Comment: @crizzis interesting are you supposed to have any annotation on the Repo? I must have read something wrong. It is also strange it works in IT. let me try removing it though.

Comment: @crizzis removing it did not help but I also agree that I shouldn't need it.